# gensim - word2vec: AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'most_common'

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

```
PAD = 0
UNK = 1
START = 2
END = 3
def make_vocab(wc, vocab_size):
    word2id, id2word = {}, {}
    word2id['<pad>'] = PAD
    word2id['<unk>'] = UNK
    word2id['<start>'] = START
    word2id['<end>'] = END
    for i, (w, _) in enumerate(wc.most_common(vocab_size), 4):
        word2id[w] = i
    return word2id
```

I got this error "AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'most_common'" when calling this function. I tried with different version of gensim. Could you give me some hints to  solve this.

Comment: As @cecil-cox notes, there's no `most_common()` method in Gensim. (Why did you think there was?) But also, what are you trying to do with this `word2id` dict and why? (If those tokens are in your training data, they'll get their own positions which should be just as good as 0-3. If they're not in your training data, reserving them positions could make other things broken/nonsensical/fragile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim's Word2Vec doesn't contain a `most_common` method.

If, for whatever reason you must extract `word,frequency` pairs from your model you can use

```
[(word, wc.w2v.vocab[word]) for word in wc.wv.vocab]
```

and sort the resulting list. This is a decidedly strange use case, however.